# Description of Struct not printed in console when executed from Unit Test

Tags: ios, swift

I have defined a Struct that adheres to the `Printable` protocol so I can inspect its value.

```
struct GridPosition : Hashable, Printable
{
    var row: Int
    var col: Int

    var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return ((row + col) * (row + col + 1)) / 2 + col
        }
    }

    var description: String {
        return "row: \(row) col: \(col)"
    }
}

func == (el: GridPosition, er: GridPosition) -> Bool {
    return el.hashValue == er.hashValue
}
```

When I print the value inside my ViewController the `description` shows up as expected in the console.

```
var pos = GridPosition(row: 1, col: 2)
println("value: \(pos)")
```

Console output:

`value: row: 1 col: 2`

However, when I try to print the value from my unit test I only get its specifier:

`value: GridTests.GridPosition`

How can I make my unit test console output more helpful? I'm using Xcode 6.2 (6C131e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly referencing the struct's `description` property.

```
println("value: \(pos.description)")
```

I believe there are other posts on SO where people note that this is a bug, at least in a playground, and explicitly referencing `description` was the recommended workaround. I haven't seen the bug rear its head in a unit test, but that may be what is going on.

Comment: That will work on single objects but not on collections (without iterating over each element).

Comment: That's true. If dealing with a collection, you could use `println(collection.map({ $0.description }))`. It is a hack, but if this is a bug, it may be the best option. Hopefully someone else will have a better solution...